# Dual boot window and Ubuntu not working on separate hard drive

Tags: dual-boot

So my laptop has 2 drives. 1 is my SSD which i ald installed my window 10 on it. Another 1 is a 2 TB HDD in which i have other stuff like games and movies. Anw, i wanted to install another Ubuntu alongside my window 10, so i shrink the HDD for 50gb. N during Ubuntu installation, i chose to partition manually as follow.

```
/dev/sda #my SSD
  /dev/sda1 ntfs 471mb #recovery partition
  /dev/sda2 efi 104mb #Window Boot manager
  /dev/sda3 16mb # idk what this is for
  /dev/sda4 ntfs 127440mb # my C drive
/dev/sdb #my HDD
  /dev/sdb1 ntfs 658219mb # my D drive
  /dev/sdb2 ntfs 1288491mb # my E drive
  /dev/sdb3 swap 4095mb # swap
  /dev/sdb4 ext4 40960mb # root
  /dev/sdb5 efi 650mb #Ubuntu boot loader installation partition
  /dev/sdb6 ext4 7980mb # home
```

After I'm done installing and restart my laptop, grub wont start to let me choose which OS to boot from. It blasted through to my window 10. So i try live install again, and it said that my computer ald has Window Boot Manager and Ubuntu 16.04 on it. So this means, i ald did install Ubuntu. I also tried advanced startup by choosing to start wit my Ubuntu, but still it got me to window 10 login. Please help me. Im new to Linux.

Comment: Ubuntu's EFI partition is too far from the start of the disk. If the HDD is an internal drive, then uses the EFI partition on th SSD for the install. PS - a 4 GB root partition is too small, it will fill quickly. If you freed 50GB why are you only using 16GB of it?

Comment: @ravery the root is 40gb not 4 lol. Also, i thought it didn't matter how far from the start of the disk as long as there's only one EFI partition on a physical hard drive. N also i did try to install bootloader into my ssd EFI partition, still it booted me to window.

Comment: You don't even need a second EFI partition, no matter where the second OS is installed, even if in a different drive.

Comment: @MichaelBay so for bootloader installation folder, i should install it to my window boot manager partition?

Comment: @AcousticMike -- ahh, I missed a zero, well in that case, it would be better to make 15GB root,  4GB swap, and the rest home (in my opinion). If the EFI boot strap can read that far into the disk then I would check that the efi partition is flagged as ESP; however I do think there is a limit. After installing to EFI partition on SSD, did you change OS boot selection in the EFI firmware settings?

Comment: The EFI partition contains your Windows boot manager, it's NOT your Windows boot manager, and can contain multiple EFI files for booting several OSes. There's no problem in having another in another drive but it's unnecessary and counterproductive complexity because you'd need to change an additional setting at UEFI. It's much easier to have only one.

Comment: @ravery lol I didn't understand after the ESP part, but please tell me how to change OS boot selection.

Comment: @MichaelBay ok i got it now. Thank for clearing this up.

Comment: @AcousticMike -- press a Function key while booting to get the firmware system setting. The key varies by make of computer but F2, F10, and F12 are common.

Comment: @ravery so F2 takes me to my BIOS, n for boot priority order i listed by Window Boot manager, SSD, hdd, usb... etc. N f12 takes me to my boot manager, it gives me 2 options, Window Boot Manager and Ubuntu, both still takes me to window.

Comment: @AcousticMike -- it is not BIOS, it is EFI Firmware Settings. with the selected OS set to WIndows, of course Windows not Ubuntu will boot. In the boot options menu (F12) are you given the option to select a specific file to boot? On a side note, is secure boot on? Try with secure boot off.

Comment: @ravery did some digging online, turned out my secure boot was enabled. So now i disabled it, n choose ubuntu wit boot option. Now i can boot from Ubuntu. Thank you for ur immense help.

Comment: Ubuntu should be able to boot with Secure Boot enabled. Check for /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi.